# Difference Between Sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier and CART

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, cart-analysis

Understand the difference between CART and DecisionTreeClassifier of Sklearn.

In Sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart), it says that "**scikit-learn uses an optimised version of the CART algorithm**". However, I couldn't find what this optimisation was anywhere!

It would be great if you could help me figure out what sort of optimisation happens here and what are the differences between the 2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fdbaa58acbead5a254f2e6d597dc1ab3b947f4c6/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L584), they reference

```
    .. [2] L. Breiman, J. Friedman, R. Olshen, and C. Stone, "Classification
           and Regression Trees", Wadsworth, Belmont, CA, 1984.
    .. [3] T. Hastie, R. Tibshirani and J. Friedman. "Elements of Statistical
           Learning", Springer, 2009.
    .. [4] L. Breiman, and A. Cutler, "Random Forests",
           https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm
```